# PHP : how to get first cell value from each row in phpspreadsheet

Tags: php

I am using a phpspreadsheet from

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/accessing-cells/#looping-through-cells

```
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($upload_path);
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            print_r($cellIterator);
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE); 
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                $emailid = $cell->getValue();
            }
```

The above is the code I use which iterates the celliterator and prints all the cells in the row, but I just need the first row.

Comment: So dont do it in a loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly then how to do it